# The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, async-await, windows-phone-toolkit

I am calling async method on demised of `CustomMessageBox` left button click. But its giving me complie time error. I googled for it but get some information regarding [MessageDialog.Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593501/the-await-operator-can-only-be-used-within-an-async-lambda-expression). How I will achieve same in windows phone `CustomMessageBox`.

Here is my code

```
CustomMessageBox customMBox = new CustomMessageBox()
                {
                    Caption = "Alert!",
                    Message = string.Format("Clicking on clear all will clear all the data on the app. Are you sure you want to proceed?"),
                    LeftButtonContent = "Yes",
                    RightButtonContent = "No",
                };

                customMBox.Dismissed += (s2, e2) =>
                {
                    switch (e2.Result)
                    {
                        case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                            await clearDatabaseAsync();
                            break;
                        case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
                            break;
                        case CustomMessageBoxResult.None:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                };

                customMBox.Show();

    public async Task clearDatabaseAsync()
    {
       //SQLite clear table record logic
        await App.DeleteDatabase();           

    }
```

can anyone please suggest me how I will achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like error says - use `async lambda expression`:

```
customMBox.Dismissed += async (s2, e2) => // rest of the code ...
```